# Installation of program for fotobook

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded program for creation of fotobook. Unfortunately, web page is in Slovenian, but there's option for German as well. Being a beginner I have problems installing the program in ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. 
link https://www.cewe.si/fotoprogram.html?clos=linux
There's a script I downloaded with name install.pl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Slovenian script or Slovenian license terms. German EULA file has to be used together with Slovenian install.pl

Comment: Tried to use it after a year. After updating the application, it doesn't start. I re-installed it, but it wouldn't run. I think installation was correct. Maybe the problem is in new distribution of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

As you have downloaded the archive [setup_CEWE_FOTOSVET.tgz](https://dls.photoprintit.com/download/Data/17409-sl_SI/hps/setup_CEWE_FOTOSVET.tgz) you need to extract it, and run Perl installer script:

```
./install.pl
```

It will download 250 Mb and install all needed components to `~/CEWE/CEWE FOTOSVET`.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. In terminal, the wording is: Data EULA.txt not found!. (In Slovenian language.) Apparently, process wants me to agree to licence terms, written in a file EULA.txt, which came in a package together with Install.pl. It's location is in the same directory as Install.pl (directory Downloads).

Comment: are you running the script from within the folder? if yes, see if the script name in the perl script under `$FILE_EULA` is the same as the name of the file in your folder as it should work.